# best way to change 2d sprite to animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I have a GameObject for **Chest**(with Collider and SpriteRenderer)

By default it is a static sprite on the screen

now i want to add animation to this game object when open is triggered (by script), **I do not have Idle animation, idle animation must be the sprite itself**

what is the best to add an animation(no looping, 1 time and then show the animated sprite) to sprite?

I can do it by adding the sprite array and using an coroutine to set the sprite periodically with 0.2f delay (it work fine but not sure if it is the only way which using coroutine with delays to simulate an animation by myself...).

I can do it by create 1 more GameObject with the Animator, when the box open event is triggered, I set the original GameObject to inactive and instantiate the GameObject with the animation (but it requires to create 2 prefabs for two different gameObject).

But none of them look proper way to do this. What is the best solution for this?

Comment: If you want to animate a "sprite" you need to change the "sprite". You can check puppet 2d for creating 2d animations or you can look up 2d character atlas map.

Comment: i knew how to create 2d animation, i need to know how to add animation to sprite without an idle animation (as idle means the static sprite),but using animation controller cannot assign an static sprite